# Perl Selenium::ActionChains move_to_element not working

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a menu dropdown. The dropdown appears when the mouse pointer is on a menu element. The workaround can be by clicking on the menu element aslo but that sometimes is giving error due to wait time being large or small depending on the speed of site.Thus, I want to use ActionChains move_to_element for this. But it is not working no errors nothing but not working.

```
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(binary=>"D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
my $action_chains = Selenium::ActionChains->new(driver => $driver);
$elem = $driver->find_element(".//*[\@id='navl']/li[3]/a"); 
$action_chains->move_to_element($elem);
$driver->pause(5000);
$driver->find_element_by_xpath(".//*[\@id='navl']/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a")->click;
$driver->pause(50000);
$driver->shutdown_binary;
```

Comment: Could you share a demo HTML page where we could verify the issue?

Comment: You can test it on Google by making it to hover over the Google Search button. Or please send me any working example you have so that I can test it on my system. Thanks

Comment: Anyone has any examples here or any comments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is of any help - there are many questions about Selenium actions and action chains and many suggestions - I struggled with a similar problem, using Python Selenium bindings though.

First of all in the code above, it could be that there is no final perform() method called after move_to_element

Secondly - and that thing was my own problem and the source of lots of bafflement on my side - i discovered that in my case, after a single perform(), i couldn't reuse the same ActionChains object - there was no error or complaint, but something was not happening right. After I created a new ActionChains object, the subsequent new chain of actions and the final perform() worked as expected.